# Getting wrong zero values with numpy fromfile when reading binary files

Tags: numpy, binary, ascii, fromfile

I am trying to read a binary file with Python. This is the code I use:

```
fb = open(Bin_File, "r")
a = numpy.fromfile(fb, dtype=numpy.float32)
```

However, I get zero values at the end of the array. For example, for a case where `nrows=296` and `ncol=439` and as a result, `len(a)=296*439`, I get zero values for `a[-922:]`. I know these values should be noData (-9999 in this example) from a trusted piece of code in R. Does anybody know why I am getting these non-sense zeros?

P.S: I am not sure it is related on not, but `len(a)` is `nrows*ncols+2`! I have to get rid of these two using `a = a[0:-2]` so that when I reshape them into rows and columns using `a_reshape = a.reshape(nrows, ncols)` I don't get an error.

Comment: try opening with `"rb"` tag instead of `"r"` ?

Comment: hmmm, you should probably tag this question with the R tag and post your R read commands or the code that actually wrote the file.

Comment: maybe the software that wrote the file adds 2 extra fields above and beyond the raw binary?  I know (by default) Fortran 90 adds two blocks that indicate how much data is there.

Comment: @Gabriel Using `"rb"` instead of `"r"` solved all of the problems. The numpy array now totallt makes sense. Do you mind moving your comment to answer so that I can vote it up?

Comment: added answer and some explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When opening a file for reading as binary you should use the mode `"rb"` instead of `"r"`.

Here is some background from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).  On linux machines you don't need the `"b"` but it wont hurt.  On Windows machines you must use `"rb"` for binary files.

Also note that the two extra entries you're getting is a common bug/feature when using the "unformatted" binary output format of Fortran.  Each write statement given in this mode will produce a record that is surrounded by two 4 byte blocks.

These blocks represent integers that list the number of bytes in the block of unformatted data.  For example,  [223] [223 bytes of data] [223].

Comment: Awesome! It totally worked. Using `"rb"` instead of `"b"` solved the problems with non-sense zero. 

The binary code was created using Fortran and it still has two numbers more than `ncols*nrows` as you mentioed. I used `a = a[0:-2]` to get rid of them.

Comment: thanks, you can accept the answer by clicking on the green arrow on the left.

Comment: actually, be careful removing the last two. Fortran will add a 4 byte int at the beginning and one at the end. These indicate how big the data block is and can be used for verification.  you probably want `a = a[1:-1]`.

Comment: That's a very good point. I checked the binary file and it seems that there are two very small numbers at `a[0]` and `a[-1]`. Using `a = a[1:-1]` is the way to go.